# split a file by a character and add it to the data

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have a question that I would like to make simpler, how do I split the second field of a file (space delimited) by an underscore and add the second part as a new field to the data (output as tab)?

e.g. 
`file.txt`

```
2 1_123
2 2_345
```

`out.tab`:

```
2 1_123 123
2 2_345 345
```

I have it working with this but is there a simpler way? This seems way too convoluted...

```
paste -d' ' file.txt <(cat file.txt | cut -d'_' -f 2- ) | tr [:blank:] \\t > out.temp && mv out.temp out.tab
```

Comment: Does it have to be done with `cut` and `paste`? How about `awk -F_ '{print $0,$2}' file.txt`?

Comment: steeldriver, that is a great point, I didn't think about this! thank you! I would still need to add the first column, but thanks for viewing this in a different way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your transformations are shuffling data inside the same line of the file, so it would be a lot simpler to use a tool that manipulates data line by line, such as sed or awk.

```
sed -e 's/^[^ \t]*[ \t][^ \t]*_\([^_ \t]*\)/&\1\t/' -e 'y/ /\t/' <<<'2 1_123'
```

Explanation: use a regular expression to match the first field (up to the first space or tab), the second field up to its last underscore, and the second field after the last underscore (which is placed in a `\(…\)` group so that it can be used in the replacement text). Keep the same text (`&` in the replacement) followed by the content of the matched group (`\1`). Any field after the second is left unchanged. Finally, replace all spaces by tabs.

If your sed doesn't support `\t` to mean a tab, use a literal tab character instead.

Comment: Thank you... this is quite complicated for non-coders so thank you very much for explaining!

Comment: Note that `[^ \t]` is required by POSIX to match any character but space backslash and `t`. (GNU `sed` only complies when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment).

Answer (score 2):

For the simple example you show where there is only one underscore and that is on the second and last field, you can do:

```
$ sed 's/_\(.*\)/& \1/' file | tr ' ' '\t'
2   1_123   123
2   2_345   345
```

Or, if your `sed` implementation supports extended regular expressions:

```
$ sed -E 's/_(.*)/& \1/' file | tr ' ' '\t'
2   1_123   123
2   2_345   345
```

This will match the first `_` and everything after that. The parentheses capture the matched string and we can refer to it on the right hand of the substitution as `\1`. `&` is everything that was matched, so the `_` followed by the rest of the 2nd field. The replacement, therefore, will print itself, a space and the characters after the `_`. The `tr` replaces all spaces with tabs.

---

For more complex cases, where you can have arbitrary numbers of fields and any of them could contain `_`, you could use `perl`:

```
$ perl -lane 's/ +/\t/g; $F[1]=~/_(\S+)/; print "$_\t$1"' file 
2   1_123   123
2   2_345   345
```

The `-a` makes `perl` split its input on whitespace into the array `@F`. The 2nd field, is `$F[1]` because arrays start counting at `0`. The `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e`". The `-l` removes trailing newlines from the input line and adds a newline to each `print` call.

`s/ +/\t/g;` replaces all occurrences of one or more spaces with tabs, `$F[1]=~/_(\S+)/;` matches the characters after the `_` in the second field and saves them as `$1` and the `print "$_\t$1"` will print the current line (`$_`) followed by whatever was matched.

---

Another useful tool for field based data is `awk`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ /,"\t");l=$2; sub(/.*_/,"",l); print $0"\t"l}' file 
2   1_123   123
2   2_345   345
```

In `awk`, input lines are automatically split on whitespace and become `$1`m `$2` ... `$N`. The `gsub(/  */,"\t");` replaces all spaces with tabs; `l=$2` saves the second field as `l`; `sub(/.*_/,"",l);` removes everything up to and including the `_` from `l`; and `print $0"\t"l` prints the line (`$0`) followed by a tab and the modified 2nd field.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I do have many underscores so this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
t=$(printf \\t)
sed "s/[^ _]*\(_\([^ _]*\)\)\{0,1\}[^ ]*/& \2/2;s/  */$t/g" <in >out
```

...should work for any number of _ in the second field, or any number of fields. it does convert any sequence of spaces to a single tab character, though. if two consecutive spaces should count as two field delimiters, use:

```
y/ /$t/
```

...at the end there rather than the...

```
s/  */$t/
```

...substitution.